# How to create an origin-destination matrix from two vectors (in R or Stata)

Tags: r, matrix, stata

I have a dataset of commuting by individuals, like this:

```
id    Origin Destination
 1         1           3   
 2         1           4   
 3         2           1
 4         2           3 
 5         2           1
 6         3           4
```

where "id" are the individuals, "origin" and "destinations" are cities.

I want to construct an origin-destination matrix, like:

```
        City1 City2 City3 City4
  City1     0     0     1     1
  City2     2     0     1     0
  City3     0     0     0     1
```

etc

Someone know how to do this in R or Stata?

Additionally:

I may need to weight the flows by the population of the city of origin. Example:

```
id    Origin Destination OriginPop
 1         1           3         5
 2         1           4         5
 3         2           1        10
 4         2           3        10
 5         2           1        10
 6         3           4         7
```

where "OriginPop" is the total population of the city of origin.

An then I want a weighted origin-destination matrix, like:

```
        City1 City2 City3 City4
  City1     0     0   1/5   1/5
  City2  2/10     0  1/10     0
  City3     0     0     0   1/7
```

etc

Comment: For your first point try `table(df$Origin,df$Destination)` with df being a data.frame of your dataset

Comment: @Tensibai, I'll try it later and let you kno if worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Tensibai, it worked fine! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add an answer to the second part of your question, and add a few things to what @Tensibai already suggested
Here is your data:

```
cities<-data.frame(id=c(1:6),Origin=c(1,1,2,2,2,3),Destination=c(3,4,1,3,1,4),OriginPop=c(5,5,10,10,10,7))
```

If I were you I would convert the cities to factors, that way, even if a city doesn't appear on your Origin or Destination (such as your example where 2 doesn't appear in Destination and 4 doesn't show in Origin) it will still appear on your table, so you can just do this:

```
cities[,2:3]<-lapply(cities[,2:3],factor,levels=c(1:4))
```

Then as @Tensibai suggested you can simply do :

```
mytable<-table(cities$Origin,cities$Destination)
mytable
  1 2 3 4
1 0 0 1 1
2 2 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 1
4 0 0 0 0
```

As for the second part, I would create another data frame containing each unique city and its population:

```
citiespop<-data.frame(cities=unique(cities$Origin),pop=unique(cities$OriginPop))
```

And finally to get the results you want, you can just divide the rows of mytable by the population of that city:

```
mytable[citiespop$cities,]<-mytable[citiespop$cities,]/citiespop$pop
round(mytable,2) # round to make it more readable
    1    2    3    4
1 0.00 0.00 0.20 0.20
2 0.20 0.00 0.10 0.00
3 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.14
4 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
```

Comment: First of all, many thanks! 

It worked well, but for the last line.
 "mytable[citiespop$cities,]<-mytable[citiespop$cities,]/citiespop$pop"

Returns me:

"Error in mytable[citiespop$cities,] : index out of bounds"

Comment: Hi @cassianord, sorry it took me so long to reply. That sounds weird, do you have more than 4 cities on your dataset? if so, did you change this piece of code `lapply(cities[,2:3],factor,levels=c(1:4))`  to the actual number of cities, so instead of 4 put total number of distinct cities.

Comment: No problem! Look, i think there is a problem in the "lapply" function after all, maybe because my origin and destination variables are numbers (codes) that must be read as strings. Something like a zipcode. After the "lapply", my data set becomes empty, and the origin-destination matrix contains only zeros. Also, the codes are changed to numbers (1,2,3 and so on), which is also a problem. Oh, and yes, I have changed the code to my number of cities.

Comment: Hey @cassianord. Let's do something else then. Could you try doing this : `zip<-unique(c(df$Origin,df$Destination))` then do `lapply(cities[,2:3],factor,levels=zip)`  and run the remainder of the code as is. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked for the last problem: the dataset is no longer empty after the "lapply". But the original problem persists: "Error in mytable[citiespop$cities,] : index out of bounds"

Comment: Okay, that makes sense, now could you try changing that line of code to : `mytable[as.numeric(citiespop$cities),]<-mytable[as.numeric(citiespop$cities),]/citiespop$pop`

Comment: Changed, but the problem persists!

Comment: That's not good, would it be possible for you to add some of your real data to your question? you can do `dput(head(df,n=20))` and paste that into your question, maybe that might give me a better insight of what is happening. df is your original data frame